# How to improve execution time for the last tasks on Standalone cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I have this code:

```
JavaRDD<Document> termDocsRdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("D:/tmp11", 20).flatMap(
    new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String,String>, Document>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Document> call(Tuple2<String,String> tup) { 
            return Arrays.asList(DocParse.parse(parsingFunction(tup)); 
        }
    }
);
```

Here I take text files from local storage (not distributed filesystem) and normalize them (each file ~ 100 KB - 1.5 MB). **parsingFunction** doesn't have any Spark functions like **map** or **flatMap** etc. It doesn't contain any data distribution functions.

When I start the app on standalone cluster first I see that workload of all CPUs of worker machine is full (100%), I see in console:

```
14/12/09 18:30:41 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8,     fujitsu11., PROCESS_LOCAL, 1377 bytes)
14/12/09 18:30:41 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 12873     ms on fujitsu11. (1/12)
14/12/09 18:30:42 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9,     fujitsu11., PROCESS_LOCAL, 1327 bytes)
14/12/09 18:30:42 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 14001     ms on fujitsu11. (2/12)
14/12/09 18:30:44 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10,     fujitsu11., PROCESS_LOCAL, 1327 bytes)
14/12/09 18:30:44 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 15925     ms on fujitsu11. (3/12)
...
```

Later I see that last tasks are executing much slower - CPUs workload ~ 15%:

```
14/12/09 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in     33373 ms on fujitsu11. (11/12)
14/12/09 18:32:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) in     104181 ms on fujitsu11. (12/12)
```

How can I increase performance of this code?

My cluster is a single master machine and another machine for a slave. All machines have 8 cores CPU and 16 GB RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 8 executor cores (the ones on the slave). The RDD probably has 20 partitions (from the `wholeTextFiles` call). When the job starts 20 tasks are created and the executor picks up 8 of them. When one task is finished, a new one is picked up. Eventually there will be less than 8 tasks remaining, and executor threads will start becoming idle. You see the CPU use gradually decrease before the job completes.

Note that you are using one machine (the master is not performing work) and a distributed computing system. This is fine for development and when you don't care about performance. But if you want to improve performance, use more than one machine or do not use Spark.

Comment: Thanks Man! And could You explain me - from what depends the number of partitions if I want to change it? Is it depends from files count or from my cores count? How should I scale this value with changing numbers of files and cores? Thank You!!!

Comment: You can set a different partition count with `sc.wholeTextFiles()`. Even with just 1 worker you may get a better performance with a higher number of partitions. Though it is not useful to have more partitions than files, since you work with whole files. You can also use `rdd.repartition()` to change the number of partitions on a pre-existing RDD.

Comment: Man! I'm thinking about your answer, and it's a little bit confusing me... Correct please me, if I'm wrong.. For example - I'll add 2 workers (each have 8 cores). So, totally I'll have 3 workers and 24 cores. Lets suppose that I'll increase partition value  in `wholeTextFiles` call to 50. Am I right that I'll see the same thing - first groups of tasks will load all cores, and they will be operated fast, and the last remaining groups of tasks will be operated by few cores and this will take more time?

Comment: Yes, except later tasks will not be slower than earlier tasks. Each task is processed in a single thread on a single core. So when you are processing the last task (file), there will be 23 idle cores and just 1 core working. It will be working at the same speed as before, but there is nothing left to do for the other 23 cores. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Man sorry I'm so annoying, but I want to find truth...  I set partition value - 24 (equal to the cores value) - and it would be logical to assume, that all cores will be loaded till the end of the whole task? Because there are 24 partitions and all cores operate them in parallel. But in practice I see the same thing, that last tasks are operating by only few cores. Can You explain it for me? Thank You, Man!

Comment: In that case all executor threads pick up one task and start working on it. There are no free tasks left. When one executor finishes, they have nothing more to do. They idle. Unless all the tasks take the same amount of time to process, you will see the executor threads gradually become idle. If it's still not clear, I'll make a picture :).

Comment: Mystic... what I wouldn't do - nothing change the performance... I tried to compare performance with two, with three, even with four worker-machines (32 cores!) and I see the same result (Of course I tried different values of minPartitions).. This code spends equal time in all these configurations... Man, how do You think - is there any bottleneck? Maybe network routing may contibute on results or it was a bad idea to put files manually on each node's local filesystem and I need to use distributed filesystem like HDFS? Hope You'll something advise! Thank You!!!

Comment: Man, I achieve some progress. I cached RDDs in my code and now adding each worker increase the performance.